# Iterating through Array of Dictionaries of [String:AnyObject]

Tags: swift

I've got problems iterating through an Array of Dictionaries (I hope that's correct).

With `let x = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: xml, options: .mutableContainers, format: &format)` I read a plist and convert it.
Works fine so far. The result is:

[image]

With `let y = x["transactions"]` I get the 110 elements. But how can I run through this array?

```
for item in y! {
    let myValue = item["myKey"]
}
```

doesn't work. Error is:

> For-in loop requires 'AnyObject' to conform to 'Sequence'

```
for i in 0..<y!.count {
    let myValue = y[i]["myKey"]
}
```

doesn't work either. `let myValue = y[i]["myKey"]` leads to two errors:

> No exact matches in call to subscript
> Reference to member 'subscript' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

How do I reach all these 110 elements?

Comment: Untrelated but `mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift (especially if the result is assigned to a `let` constant) and property list values are always `Any` (value type) rather than `AnyObject` (reference type). Consider to decode the data into a model using `PropertyListDecoder`.

Comment: Incase it was missed at the end of the comment by @vadian, using `PropertyListDecoder` into an appropriate model (set of structs) is much better than loading the plist into an `Any` using `PropertyListSerialization`.

Answer (score -1):

OK solution found.

```
let y = x["transactions"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
```

works so far.